# Laravel SMTP Email

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, xampp

Start working with Laravel 4.2 I tried to send email using Gmail STMP server. Below is my app/config/mail.php.

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'sample_address@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Sample'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'sample_address@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'sample password',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
);
```

Below is my php code.

```
<!-- app/views/emails/welcome.php -->
Mail::send('emails.welcome', 'Laravel Admin', function($msg) {
   $msg->from('sample_address@gmail.com', 'Laravel Admin');
   $msg->to('sample_receiver@gmail.com');
});
```

But it does not work. I have already configured my XAMPP php.ini on my MAC OSX. It only works when sending a normal PHP mail, not SMTP. The error message that I've got from Laravel on the view page is '**Error in exception handler**'. I would like to see more error information but I don't know how to get more info. What is wrong with my code? What else do I need to do or configure? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

you can put your email and name in Input

```
Input::merge(array('email'=>'sample_receiver@gmail.com','name'=>'sample_name')); 

Mail::send('emails.welcome', 'Laravel Admin', function($msg) {
   $msg->from('sample_address@gmail.com', 'Laravel Admin');
   $msg->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))->subject('You have');
});
```

also change 'encryption'

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'sample_address@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Sample'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'sample_address@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'sample password',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change 'encryption' for ssl and in your gmail must be enabled IMAP access in config

Comment: Please add this as a comment

Answer (score 0):

When you are having problems with sending mails via gmail, try this. It worked for me.

Login with your gmail account and then go to:
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and click continue. Then, you have few minutes to send your mail with your code.
After this, Google will allow sign in to that account from the new source.