# Laravel mail parameters (sendmail/smtp)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp, sendmail

I'm trying to figure out how to set my mail parameters.

I have a domain name **production.mydomain.be**. I've created a mail address **no-reply@mydomain.be**. But my question is now, how do I set my mail parameters? Do I chose sendmail or smtp?

The Laravel documentation is not saying much about sendmail / smtp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709988/laravel-smtp-email

Comment: This is not about Laravel, it's about your server. Do you have a mail server installed on your server (Postfix for example) ?

Comment: Postfix is installed. Should I use smtp.mydomain.be instead of smtp.gmail.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose `smtp`

You need to fill `username` and `password` fields in order to login with the smtp server, and also provide the valid information for that connection with the `host` and the `port`. Your server manage should give you that information, along with the encryption.